Converting list object (home range) to an object I can plot?
I have an example dataset (named "data") with coordinates as shown below (projected in CRS 5321):
longitude latitude
    430547.6  7208993
    404139.3  7212760
    411915.5  7232663
    430181.8  7239410
    431756.6  7245202
    436880.9  7267675
    453830.3  7216400
    465987.5  7210260
    473772.0  7180114
    478228.2  7182945

I am trying to calculate the home range of this dataset. I chose 95% kde using the package ks in R. The code I have to calculate this home range is shown below:
  library(ks)
h1 <- Hpi(data, pilot = "samse", binned = T)
  home.range <- kde(data, H = h1)

This returns an object of type list. I would now like to plot my home range, but it is currently the wrong object type. How do I convert it to an object I can plot (for example, as a matrix with x-y coordinates)?

what exactly do you want to plot from the home.range object? You have x, eval.points, estimate, H, gridtype, gridded, binned, names, w, type, cont

It would be the eval.points

Add the following lines to your code (these require the package grDevices):
cont = contourLevels(kernPI1, cont = 95) # Can modify the 95 if you want something smaller than a 95% home range
line = contourLines(x = kernPI1$eval.points[[1]], y =
                        kernPI1$eval.points[[2]], 
                      z = kernPI1$estimate,
                      level = cont)

# Extract x y coordinates
x<-line[[1]][["x"]]
y<-line[[1]][["y"]]

# Convert to dataframe and plot points
line2<-data.frame(x,y)
plot(line2)

